# Module not found: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' while using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I got this error : Module not found: Can't resolve './serviceWorker' in '/home/radu/Desktop/ReactAppStudents/barbut/src'

Here is my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter as BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//reportWebVitals();
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And here is my App.js where I'm trying to use React Router.

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter , Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./Login";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";

function App() {
  return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <h1>Index</h1>} />
        <Route path={"/login"} component={()=> <h1>Login</h1>} />
        <Route path={"/home"} component={<h1>Home</h1>} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does the file `./serviceWorker.js` exist in the same directory as the `index.js`?

Comment: You might have used a different project template that doesn't include the ServiceWorker.js file. There's some magic and default behaviour in CRA that is poorly explained and confusing to both learners and experienced developers. 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10104

Most apps don't need service workers. Your app will probably work fine if you just remove the import and `.unregister()` line from your index.js

Answer (score 2):

Create a file name serviceWorker.js

src/serviceWorker.js

with these codes

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all '
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the app with create-react-app version 4+, the default project template has changed, and service worker is now opt in, and no longer included by default.

So just remove any reference of serviceWorker from your index.js. Also, you should not include the BrowserRouter component in both index.js and App.js. Once is enough.

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

side note: There's a new feature that is included by default in version 4+ in index.js called `reportWebVitals`, but it has nothing to do with service workers.